# How do to update an object within Flutter MobX ObservableList?

Tags: flutter, mobx

I'm looking for the best approach to update an ObservableList with objects.
I've created a dummy example below with Car and a store with Cars.

In JavaScript I can simply call

```
const carData = {id: 1, name: "Chrysler"};
update(carData);
```

and in the update method:

```
    @action
    updateCar(carData) {
        cars = cars.map(car => car.id === carData.id ? {...car, ...carData} : car);
    }
```

How do one achieve the same in Flutter with MobX?

```
class Car {
    int id;
    String model;
    DateTime year;
}

abstract class _CarCollectionStore with Store {
    @observable
    ObservableList<Car> cars = ObservableList<Car>();

    @computed
    get latestCar() => iterating and getting latest Car by year.

    @action
    updateCar(WHICH PARAMETERS?) {
       ...
    }
}
```

How do I actually update the Name of the latestCar?

```
carCollectionStore = Provider.of<CarCollectionStore>(context, listen: false);

carNameController = TextEditingController(text: carCollectionStore.latestCar.name);

carNameController.addListener(() {
    carCollectionStore.updateCar(carNameController.text);
});
```